# Reference request: Cover times, Mixing Times and DGFF applied in statistics?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, markov-chains, gaussian

I am trying to find if in active research in statistics, there is interest in mixing times, cover times of graphs, and/or the discrete Gaussian free field?

I haven't found anything so far for the cover time and the discrete gaussian free field. Mixing times give information on the duration of Markov Chain Monte Carlo, but I haven't seen this used in recent research.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The annals paper of Ding-Lee-Peres is a good start:
http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2012/175-3/p08 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4371

Further progress is in solo work of Ding https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4402